# Remove owncloud server from raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, owncloud

Linux noob here so please be gentle. I followed a [tutorial](https://www.avoiderrors.com/owncloud-10-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-stretch/) to install owncloud on my raspberry pi with an external hdd. Apparently owncloud doesn't play well with external hdd's so I tried to switch the data directory to `/var/www/html/owncloud/data`. This didn't work either.
I've been messing around with files and at this point I would like to uninstall owncloud and start again.

From the tutorial I installed these dependancies:

```
apt install -y apache2 mariadb-server libapache2-mod-php7.0 \
    php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl \
    php7.0-intl php7.0-mcrypt php-imagick \
    php7.0-zip php7.0-xml php7.0-mbstring
```

and `wget https://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-10.0.10.tar.bz2`.

I would like a fresh start. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.